# Delphi Array or List not being updated as expected in for loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, delphi, tlist

I have a loop that is updating the values in a 1 dimensional array (Arr2) and then adding the array to a list (ResultPnts):

```
type
  point = packed record
    case aSInt of
       0: (x, y, z: aFloat);
       1: (v: array [0 .. 2] of aFloat); { vertex }
  end;

  MyPntArr = array of point;

  EntPntArr = record
    enttyp : byte;
    zb, zh : double;    // store zbase and zheight for 2d lines/arcs
    closed : boolean;   // set true if first and last points of lines/arcs are equal
    Pnts   : MyPntArr;
  end;

  tPaths = TList<EntPntArr>;

procedure PathEntToPntArr (ent : entity; var resultPnts : tPaths);
var
  Arr1, Arr2 : EntPntArr;
  j : integer;
begin
  ...                
  setlength (Arr2.Pnts, 2);
  Arr2.closed := false;
  Arr2.enttyp := entslb;
  for j := 0 to length(Arr1.Pnts)-1-ord(Arr1.closed) do begin
    setlength (Arr2.Pnts, 2); // note: I'm not entirely sure why, but without setting length in
                              // each iteration of the loop, the array points are not updated
                              // in each subsequent iteration after the first.
    Arr2.Pnts[0] := Arr1.Pnts[j];
    // add slbthick to Arr1.Pnts[j], with result in the var parameter Arr2.Pnts[1]
    AddPnt (Arr1.Pnts[j], slbthick, Arr2.Pnts[1]);  
    resultPnts.Add(Arr2); 
  end;
```

Originally I did not have the setlength call at the start of the for loop, and in this case the appropriate number of items were being added to resultPnts, but they were all the same (as though the logic assigning to Arr2.Pnts[0] and Arr2.Pnts[1] was not being called in every iteration of the loop)

I have fixed the problem by adding the setlength call, but I don't really understand why that is necessary.  I would love to understand what is going on here so that I can more reliably avoid this sort of problem in future.

Can anybody explain to me why the code is not working as expected without the setlength in the loop?

Comment: I beliveve that problem might lie in `Arr2.Pnts[0] := Arr1.Pnts[j];` with which you are always changing the value of the first Point of your `Arr2.Pnts`. But later in your `AddPnt (Arr1.Pnts[j], slbthick, Arr2.Pnts[1]);` you are checking the value of your second Point of your `Arr2.Pnts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Dynamic arrays are reference counted.

Without the `SetLength()` inside the loop, you are adding multiple *copies* of the `Arr2` variable to `resultPnts` but they all refer to the same physical array in memory, which you are modifying on each loop iteration.  That is why all of the entries end up with the same array values assigned by the last loop iteration.

- Before the loop is entered, `Arr2.Pnts` points to an array with `refcount=1` from the initial `SetLength()`.
- The 1st loop iteration modifies the content of the existing array, then adds a copy of `Arr2` to `resultPnts`, incrementing the array's `refcount` to 2.
- The 2nd loop iteration modifies the content of the existing array, then adds a copy of `Arr2` to `resultPnts`, incrementing the array's `refcount` to 3.
- And so on, until the loop ends.
- When `PathEntToPntArr()` exits, only the reference in `Arr2.Pnts` is cleared, decrementing the array's `refcount`, but the array still has active references from all of the entries in `resultPnts`.  The array will be freed when all of those references are cleared later.

`SetLength()` has a side effect that it forces an existing dynamic array to `refcount=1` if the new size is > 0, even if the array's existing size is the same value.  If the array has `refcount=1`, `SetLength()` will modify the array in-place, otherwise it will decrement the array's `refcount` and then allocate a new array with `refcount=1`.

Thus, with `SetLength()` inside the loop, your `resultPnts` entries will each end up with a unique array assigned to them.

- Before the loop is entered, `Arr2.Pnts` points to an array with `refcount=1` from the initial `SetLength()`.
- The 1st loop iteration calls `SetLength()`, leaving the current array intact, then modifies the content of that array, then adds a copy of `Arr2` to `resultPnts`, incrementing that array's `refcount` to 2.
- The 2nd loop iteration calls `SetLength()`, decrementing the current array's `refcount` to 1 and creating a new array with `refcount=1`, then modifies the content of that new array, then adds a copy of `Arr2` to `resultPnts`, incrementing that array's `refcount` to 2.
- And so on, until the loop ends.
- When `PathEntToPntArr()` exits, only the reference in `Arr2.Pnts` is cleared, decrementing the `refcount` of the last array created.  Each array in `resultPnts` will be freed individually as their entries are cleared later.

The RTL in XE7+ has a public [`DynArrayUnique()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DynArrayUnique) function that serves the same purpose as your `SetLength()` call, eg:

```pascal
procedure PathEntToPntArr (ent : entity; var resultPnts : tPaths);
var
  Arr1, Arr2 : EntPntArr;
  j : integer;
begin
  ...                
  SetLength(Arr2.Pnts, 2);
  ...
  for j := 0 to length(Arr1.Pnts)-1-ord(Arr1.closed) do begin
    DynArrayUnique(Pointer(Arr2.Pnts), TypeInfo(point)); // <--
    ...
    resultPnts.Add(Arr2); 
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Or, you can use `System.Copy()` instead:

```pascal
procedure PathEntToPntArr (ent : entity; var resultPnts : tPaths);
var
  Arr1, Arr2 : EntPntArr;
  j : integer;
begin
  ...                
  SetLength(Arr2.Pnts, 2);
  ...
  for j := 0 to length(Arr1.Pnts)-1-ord(Arr1.closed) do begin
    Arr2.Pnts := Copy(Arr2.Pnts{0, Length(Arr2.Pnts)}); // <--
    ...
    resultPnts.Add(Arr2); 
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy for the explanation.  I was expecting something along those lines but couldn't quite explain it to myself.  I guess one of my concerns was whether or not adding setlength was a reliable solution so you have settled any concerns I had on that count.  Not sure if there are any efficiency differences between setlength, dynarrayunique or copy, but expect it would not be a major difference and not important in the context of my project.

Comment: (have changed my code to use DynArrayUnique as the reason for it being there is a little more self-explanatory.  Works well - thanks again!)

Comment: I'm not terribly sure that I like the lack of type safety in `DynArrayUnique`. I'd personally prefer `Copy` or `TArray<point>.Create(...)` (assuming you switch to generic arrays which is generally good practice anyway. Not sure if `MyPntArr.Create(...)` compiles or not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "*Not sure if `MyPntArr.Create(...)` compiles or not*" - it should, yes, per the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)).

Comment: Thanks for the ongoing comments ... I'll follow up on the comments regarding generic arrays (which I have to admit I was not really familiar with, but they do look to offer some advantage)